# Webpage not displayed correctly between browsers, mostly IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I am trying to make a website for my family's B&B and I don't have much experience with web coding.

This is a website template I bought from the internet, and I didn't have that many difficulties with it until now where I find myself completely stuck to a point where the contents of a specific webpage of the website are not displayed correctly across Chrome Firefox and Internet Explorer, mostly the problem is with IE since the viewing issues between Firefox and Chrome are close to none.

I was told on IRC that this is caused by the CSS not being read correctly from the browsers and that every browsers tend to view pages differently, and therefore I should create a specific css style for IE in order to address this compatibility issue. 
Unfortunately though I haven't been able to find out what is causing the issue.

The "container" where those contents (just pictures and texts) are located in the page is called `grid_11` and belongs to the `grid.css` file located in the css folder.

I tried to play with margin, something like

> .container_24 .grid_11 {
>       width:430px;
>           margin-left: 40px
>   }

but the result is that the box containing all the contents moves throughout the page along with them.

Here I am at attaching the screenshots of how the page is displayed across the three browsers.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dDemw.png

And here's the html code alongside with the css http://jsfiddle.net/r5QHW/

This is really getting above my pay grade now. I'd truly appreciate if someone could help me out with it.

Thanks,
Pietro

Comment: So you want us to rewrite your CSS for IE-compatability? Hire somebody.

Comment: I haven't said that. I was asking for someone to point me out to the issue, not to write the whole css for the website. But thank you anyways.

Comment: Yes, I was exaggerating. But still, looking thru your code is too much. We aren't personal debuggers.

Comment: @Segnale Stop supporting them, then they'd have motivation to stop.

Comment: @bjb568 while that is certainly an option, it is almost always a bad idea for a business, especially a small family business, to turn away potential customers based on their browser.

Comment: @CodingWithSpike But… *IE*! ***M.S.I.E.***! Seriously tho, if it takes more money to support them then what you're going to gain, it's not worth it.

Answer (score 0):

The question you want answered is one of the below... good luck!

### Where is there a list of css property support by browser?

W3schools has lots of ads but is a good resource.

- The CSS property support table: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_browsersupport.asp
- The list of all references on their site: http://www.w3schools.com/sitemap/sitemap_references.asp

---

### How do I debug code in a specific browser?

What you want is the **Developer Tools**. You actually open the page in the browser you're evaluating and then follow the instructions for each browser's developer tools to figure out what broke.

- Chrome: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/index
- Firefox: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools
- IE: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd565628%28VS.85%29.aspx